# crontab: installing new crontab - path too long

Tags: rhel, cron

Error. I tried all possible crontab entries, but nothing gets accepted. Always `path too long`

```
# crontab -e
no crontab for root - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
path too long
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.mqtSoV
[root@myhostname5 tmp]# cat /tmp/crontab.mqtSoV
0 * * * * /tmp/test.sh
```

Red Hat release

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
```

Logs. In other logs and journalctl no cron related errors.

```
Sep  5 10:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[831]: starting 0anacron
Sep  5 10:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[877]: finished 0anacron
Sep  5 10:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[831]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 10:01:02 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[886]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 10:10:01 myhostname5 CROND[1808]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 10:20:02 myhostname5 CROND[4266]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 10:30:01 myhostname5 CROND[6182]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 10:40:01 myhostname5 CROND[6825]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 10:50:01 myhostname5 CROND[8084]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:00:01 myhostname5 CROND[9467]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:01:01 myhostname5 CROND[9737]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep  5 11:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[9737]: starting 0anacron
Sep  5 11:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[9746]: finished 0anacron
Sep  5 11:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[9737]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 11:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[9752]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 11:02:16 myhostname5 crontab[9923]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:03:36 myhostname5 crontab[9923]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:03:50 myhostname5 crontab[10043]: (root) LIST (root)
Sep  5 11:04:02 myhostname5 crontab[10057]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:04:10 myhostname5 crontab[10057]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:04:13 myhostname5 crontab[10082]: (root) LIST (root)
Sep  5 11:04:29 myhostname5 crontab[10106]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:04:47 myhostname5 crontab[10106]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:05:13 myhostname5 crontab[10150]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:05:20 myhostname5 crontab[10150]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:05:45 myhostname5 crontab[10202]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:06:01 myhostname5 crontab[10202]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 11:10:01 myhostname5 CROND[10554]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:20:01 myhostname5 CROND[11984]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:30:02 myhostname5 CROND[12979]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:40:01 myhostname5 CROND[14476]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 11:50:01 myhostname5 CROND[16230]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 12:00:01 myhostname5 CROND[17257]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 12:01:01 myhostname5 CROND[17441]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep  5 12:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[17441]: starting 0anacron
Sep  5 12:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[17450]: finished 0anacron
Sep  5 12:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[17441]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 12:01:01 myhostname5 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[17456]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Sep  5 12:10:01 myhostname5 CROND[18756]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Sep  5 12:10:26 myhostname5 crontab[18864]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:10:37 myhostname5 crontab[18864]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:10:45 myhostname5 crontab[18898]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:11:12 myhostname5 crontab[18898]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:13:24 myhostname5 crontab[19828]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:13:42 myhostname5 crontab[19828]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:13:57 myhostname5 crontab[19900]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:14:09 myhostname5 crontab[19900]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:15:16 myhostname5 crontab[20132]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:15:28 myhostname5 crontab[20132]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:16:05 myhostname5 crontab[20190]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Sep  5 12:16:25 myhostname5 crontab[20190]: (root) END EDIT (root)
```

listening of crontab works. There are no symlinks in /var/..

```
# ls -ald /var/ /var/spool/ /var/spool/cron/
drwxr-xr-x. 20 root root 4096 Aug 10 19:14 /var/
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 May  2 11:42 /var/spool/
drwx------.  2 root root 4096 Jul  8  2014 /var/spool/cron/


# crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

Here the strace output at [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0f9ebf97551de55d6c9f20ca8ac36143)

I don't know what's this `debuginfo` stuff

```
# yum --enablerepo='*' install cronie-debuginfo
Loaded plugins: priorities, product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
47 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package cronie-debuginfo available.
Error: Nothing to do

# yum --enablerepo='*' search debuginfo
Loaded plugins: priorities, product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
47 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
============================================================================================== N/S matched: debuginfo ==============================================================================================
percona-xtrabackup-24-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package percona-xtrabackup-24
riemann-dash-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package riemann-dash
yum-plugin-auto-update-debug-info.noarch : Yum plugin to enable automatic updates to installed debuginfo packages
zfs-debuginfo.x86_64 : Debug information for package zfs

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: I've never seen that error before. Is any of `/var`, `/var/spool` or `/var/spool/cron` a symbolic link? Does `crontab -l` work? Run `strace -s9999 -o crontab.strace crontab -e` and post the trace file, this should give a clue of where the problem is.

Comment: thanks @Gilles I edited the posting. What does this strace command do?

Comment: `strace` shows a list of all the system calls made by the process, but it turns out that the error is reported due to an internal calculation, not to a system call, so `strace` doesn't help, sorry.

Comment: Since this is RedHat, I'd love to know what their Support team says about this error.

Comment: It's not clear from where the `path too long` comes from. Can you add another strace listing produced with `strace -fv crontab -e`?

Answer (score 5):

Your error is a little bizarre. To investigate it further you might like to install `gdb` and the debuginfo package for your crontab command so that we can see what it is trying to do. My `crontab` command is part of the `cronie` package, as I found by doing:

```
$ rpm -qf $(command -v crontab)
cronie-1.4.12-5.fc22.x86_64
```

You can install the debuginfo package for it with `dnf`:

```
$ sudo dnf --enablerepo='*-debuginfo' install cronie-debuginfo
```

You can now run your command under gdb and have access to the function names used in the C code. I found your error message occurs when `glue_strings()` is called, so set a breakpoint there. Since `crontab` is normally setuid root, you need to be root to run the gdb. (In the following `(gdb)` is printed by gdb as a prompt).

```
# gdb crontab
(gdb) break glue_strings
```

Start the program with `run` followed by the arguments to `crontab`:

```
(gdb) run -e
```

You should see a dump of the parameters passed to `glue_strings()` when it was called.

```
Breakpoint 1, glue_strings (buffer=0x7ffdaa552740 "", buffer_size=4096, 
    a=0x55c50950e567 "/var/spool/cron", b=0x55c5097154c0 <User> "meuh", 
    separator=47 '/') at misc.c:110
110             if (buffer_size <= 0)
```

Enter the command `c` to continue. There may be several calls. The last one before the program ends is the most interesting. Add this output to your original post for further diagnosis.

---

The above commands on getting debuginfo are for Fedora. For Red Hat 7.1 see [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9907) which seems to be saying list the channels with

```
subscription-manager repos --list | grep -i debug
```

and enable the one you want, eg

```
subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-rs-for-rhel-7-server-fastrack-debug-rpms
```

Comment: The above commands for getting debuginfo are for Fedora. For Red Hat 7.1 see [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/9907), including the later paragraph on 7.1.
As I don't have a subscription, if you understand what is wanted please add what you did to your original post.